# How to use IS_REAL() for ISNUMERIC in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column which have value comes number along with special character like $-,' '() . After replacing them= special character i want check if the column value is numeric or not
for that i am trying to use IS_REAL() function in snowflake but it is always returning false for the values which has actual number as well.

Below is the sample QUERY , input value out put value

INPUT COLUMN

| PROJECTED_REVENUE |
| --- |
| $16,863.03 |
| $16,416=8.58 |
| $3.711.25 |
| $22/187 |
| $0 |

```
Select is_double(TO_VARIANT(nullif(ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("Projected_Revenue",'$',''),',',''),'-',''),'(','-'),')',''))),'') ) ) = TRUE then Null 
else cast(nullif(ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("Total_Projected_Revenue",'$',''),',',''),'-',''),'(','-'),')',''))),'') as decimal(18,2)) 
from Table_Name;
```

OUTPUT

| PROJECTED_REVENUE |
| --- |
| 16863.03 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |

But i am receiving the error message

Invalid argument types for function 'IS_DOUBLE': (VARCHAR(16777216))

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that a column can only be of one datatype. Because some of the values in your "column" are strings, the whole column is treated as a string so when you convert to a variant it just contains strings.

A better solution might be to use the TRY_TO_DOUBLE function. Also, REGEX_REPLACE is probably a better approach than multiple nested REPLACE statements e.g.

```
with t1 (projected_revenue) as (
    select *
    from (values('$16,863.03'),('$16,416=8.58'),('$3.711.25'),('$22/187'),('$0'))
)
select projected_revenue
,regexp_replace(projected_revenue, '[$-,()=/]', '') cleaned
,TRY_TO_DOUBLE(cleaned) cleaned_double
from t1
;
```

Comment: when i apply  IS_DOUBLE(TRY_TO_DOUBLE  <expr> the query is not failing but it is not recognizing that the values like '$3.711.25' is not double and hence returning $3.711.25 which is incorrect in my requirement

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using IS_DOUBLE(TRY_TO_DOUBLE as the TRY function returns a double or null the IS_DOUBLE is pointless, all you need is the TRY function. Anyway, please update your question with the full SQL statement you are now running

Answer (score 1):

Please try this and let me know

select try_to_number(replace(replace(replace("Total_Projected_Revenue", '$',''),'-', ''), ',',''))
from tablename

Answer (score 0):

Convert the column to variant and then check whether the value is real or not. Please refer below code.

```
SELECT IS_REAL(TO_VARIANT(15.67)), IS_REAL(TO_VARIANT(1478)),IS_REAL(TO_VARIANT('test'));
```

In this case, the expected result is `TRUE, TRUE, FALSE`